# Unable to access elements inside Shadow Root in WCT

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom, polymer-3.x, web-component-tester, wct

In my unit test, I am unable to access dom element from shadow root.

```
var el = fixture('basic');
var imgElement = el.shadowRoot.querySelector('img');
```

I am getting null in imgElement. How to get the img element?
I have tried also,

```
var imgElement2= document.querySelector('img');
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like maybe that image is not in your element's shadowRoot, but in one of its descendants'..

Comment: Can you post what your DOM looks like and what the function `fixture` returns

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the dom element in the shadow root. Try ;

```
 this.$.<element-id>
```

or

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector(selector)  / ie:('#element-id')
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the `setup` function first

```html
   suite('test', function(){
                setup(function () {
                my-el = fixture('DefaultElement');
            });
```